# how to make user interaction disable for tab bar in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

Here while adding item to cart at that time activity indicator will animate during this time while activity indicator animates during this time user should not able to access the tab bar items can anyone help me how to implement this ?

here is my code for this

```
 var tabbarController = UITabBarController()
 loginCheck = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "CustomerLogin")
        print(loginCheck!)
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cartViewController") as! AddToCartViewController
        let vc2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchCategories") as! SearchCategoriesViewController
        let vc3 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myAccount") as! MyAccountViewController
        tabbarController.viewControllers = [vc1,vc2,vc3]
        let tabItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items as NSArray!
        let tabItem = tabItems?[1] as! UITabBarItem
```

Comment: add a view of full screen and inside it add activity indicator  so when activity indicator  animates view.isHidden  = false when activity indicator  stops animating view.isHidden = true

Comment: is it not possible to disable user interaction for tab bar controller  ? @D.Desai

Comment: it is.. but u have to stop userInteraction of all menu, your cell,tabs  or any other action.. so its better to have a view which stops all interaction automatically

Comment: y to go for that I just used view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false this code to stop all user interactions @D.Desai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle whole app user interaction then do the following-

To disable **User interaction:**

```
 UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

To enable **User interaction:**

```
if(UIApplication.shared.isIgnoringInteractionEvents){

        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    }
```

Comment: I need to declare this UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents() in my view controller ?

Comment: Yes When you need to disable user interaction add this code. And when you done your execution, enable it again.